# Octoprint: Reducing Camera Lag Time?

Tags: octoprint

I've got a webcam (Logitech ProductID_2470, according to my Mac) attached to my Octopi running on a RPi 3B.

I am able to get the video on the Octoprint display page, but the lag is huge: over 50 seconds.

How can I diagnose the problem and reduce this lag time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a slow Wifi connection.  It was fast enough for the low bandwidth of printer commands and status reports, but the video feed was overwhelming the connection.

Adding a Wifi repeater increased the bandwidth and fixed the issue.